# CSS3 - animate text align left/center/right

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I've got **one line (not wrapped)** text inside full width div.

Is it possible to animate this element `text alignment` so text moves to given side/center - I know I could mensure width and use `relative/absolute positioning`, but I dont find it straight solution and it also may cause some responsive issues?

Here is [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/LNfqj/) without animations yet.

Comment: Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/LNfqj/1/) ;)

Comment: @mdesdev center is not text-align center…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed something similar today. I wanted a button that started with text aligned to the right, but then animated the text to center on hover/focus.

Here is what I came up with. The problem I have with several of the answers I have found is that they animate "position", which is [not very performant](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/). I wanted to use only "transform". This is a lot of markup just for centering button text, but seems to work well.

```css
body {margin: 0}
ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  width: 30%;
  padding: 10px 0;
}
button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0;
}
.center-line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 2px;
  height: 100%;
  background: lightgray;
  left: 15%;
  top: 0;
}

.outer {
  text-align: right;
  transition: 200ms transform;
}
.inner {
  display: inline-block;
  transition: 200ms transform;
}

button:hover .outer {
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
button:hover .inner {
  transform: translateX(50%);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <button>
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">Text 1</div>
      </div>
    </button>
   </li>
  <li>
    <button>
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">Text Two</div>
      </div>
    </button>
   </li>
  <li>
    <button>
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">Text Longer Three</div>
      </div>
    </button>
   </li>
</ul>
<span class="center-line" />
```

Comment: @Brat thats clever! Would be great if you could edit your answer and describe a bit main trick you're doing here - transforming outer holder 50% one side and transforming child holder 50% other side.

Answer (score 2):

`text-align` property is not animatable, so you can't use it with css transition nor with jquery animate .. Your best shot would be the positioning (use percentage units to retain responsivity).

Hope this helps ...

Comment: Ok I get it. Anyway, percents will not help for responsivity as container width will change, but text font size > width of text itself will stay the same

Answer (score 0):

Maybe javascript created marquee would help you out here? `<marque>` tag is not best way but maybe js marquee would suit you.
[Marquee (with optional start/stop buttons)](http://www.felgall.com/jstip109.htm)

Update: As I understand that marquee would not be best for your needs I came out with another solution using margin-left and changing its value.

Value for right button would depend on how long text you would have there but you can always check that width [elements width](https://api.jquery.com/width/) and adjust in code. I have updated the fiddle with that change in mind: [final Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LNfqj/5/)

Comment: how would you like to use it to change text alignment?

Comment: I assumed you want to animate your text through entire div to the side but after that comment it looks like that is not the case?

Comment: Indeed I want, but I dont find how you will know when to start - stop Marquee or make css easing etc?

Comment: I've updated the answer. I have removed text-alignment and made that using margin-left.

Comment: your anthoer solution is not responsive tho :) Anyway I'm glad for your effort.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LNfqj/10/ - this is my final solution - need only once to be managed via js and then changing css class is enoght