# How to style the value atrribute in the input tag?

Tags: html, css, attributes

My input type is a button and I want to customize the style of the value attribute and want to move it a little to the left. Also there are other input buttons as well. I want to apply the style only to this input button.
Here is the code:

```
<input  style="width:85px;margin-left:-5px" type="button" value="Discuss" 
 onclick="location.href=''" name="sub" class="button-add  mebutton">
```

Comment: you want a button to move left or button text?

Comment: @Saurabh Solanki The text in the button.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want transition on hover of a button then you can use this link to get an idea of how to do that.

[CSS3 - animate text align left/center/right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22923524/css3-animate-text-align-left-center-right)

check the answer of @Bart you can do something like that.

for other animation and effects of button check [this](https://freebiesupply.com/blog/css-button-hover-effects/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" value="Discuss" 
 onclick="location.href=''" name="sub" class="button-add  mebutton">
```

add this in css

```
<style>
        input[type=button]
                         {
                            margin-left:10px;
                            width:85px;
                          }
    </style>
```

Comment: I think this will move the button,no?

Comment: yeah it will move the button, try this if you not get the answer post your jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline styles and apply the styles from the class you have added `mebutton`. If you think the mebutton class added all the places, then add some new class for this button and apply it. Use `text-align` property to align your text left/right and use the padding for the position of the text.

```
.mebutton {
   width:85px;
   text-align:left;
   padding-left:10px;
}
```

Same I have added in the following snippet.

```css
.mebutton {
  width:85px;
  text-align:left;
  padding-left:10px;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Discuss" 
 onclick="location.href=''" name="sub" class="button-add  mebutton">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="btnstyle" type="button" value="Discuss" onclick="location.href=''" name="sub">
```

add this css

```
<style>
```

.btnstyle { color: blue; font-size : 24px;}